# Is it possible to make AutoMapper reusing custom converter instance when mapping a list of objects

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

I'm using .Net6 and AutoMapper (11.0.1) to map one type to another using a custom converter. Notice I use DI

```
public class FromToTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<From, To>
{
    public FromToTypeConverter(ILogger<FromToTypeConverter> logger, ISomeService someService)
    {
        // set private fields with injected logger and service...
    }
    
    public To Convert(From source, To destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // mapping logic....
    }
}
```

In my configureservices I register all like:

```
services.AddScoped<ISomeService, SomeService>();
services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

I have my mapping telling AutoMapper to use my converter like this:

```
CreateMap<From, To>().ConvertUsing<FromToTypeConverter>();
```

If I have a list of From objects I want to map to To objects I do:

```
var toObjs = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<To>>(fromObjs);
```

I noticed that AutoMapper creates a new instance of my typeconverter for each object it converts in the list.

Isn't it possible to tell AutoMapper to re-use the converter instance?

Comment: Does it work when you use the overload `ConvertUsing(new FromToTypeConverter())`?

Comment: Yes, but I prefer using DI since I want some more injected into my converter. I'll update question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code how you register the services like `ISomeService` so AutoMapper can inject them into your `FromToTypeConverter`.

Comment: Try registering the converter _before_ `AddAutoMapper`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution.

If I tell AutoMapper to use my converter like this:

```
CreateMap<From, To>().ConvertUsing<ITypeConverter<From, To>>();
```

And registers the custom type converter into the DI system like:

```
services.AddScoped<ITypeConverter<From, To>, FromToTypeConverter>();
```

Then it only creates one instance for my scope.